# Перевод каждого элемента массива

Tags: flutter, dart

Имеется массив:

```
List distanceUnits = [ LengthUnit.inch, LengthUnit.foot, LengthUnit.yard, LengthUnit.mile LengthUnit.millimeter, LengthUnit.centimeter, LengthUnit.meter, LengthUnit.kilometer,];
```

Как присвоить каждому элементу 2-е значение для перевода?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Использовать [Map](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-core/Map-class.html):

```
Map<LengthUnit, LengthUnitRu> distanceUnits = <LengthUnit, LengthUnitRu>{LengthUnit.inch: LengthUnitRu.inch, LengthUnit.yard: LengthUnitRu.yard, ...};
```

### Использовать свой класс:

```
class Locale {
  Locale(this.unit, this.unitRu);

  final LengthUnit unit;
  final LengthUnitRu unitRu;
}

List<Locale> distanceUnits = <Locale>[Locale(LengthUnit.inch, LengthUnitRu.inch), Locale(LengthUnit.yard, LengthUnitRu.yard), ...];
```